# How do you escape "-" in a command in the Shell (Zsh)?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I am trying to rename a file named "-a" to "a" using the command line (zsh shell). I have tried the following

```
mv \-a "a"
mv '\-a' "a"
mv "\-a" "a"
```

but got

```
mv: illegal option -- a
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

each time. Is there a way to escape "-a" or any other command option in the shell?

Comment: How is this question related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: The question is off-topic here and will be closed soon.

Comment: [Why cat, grep and other commands can't understand files starting with minus sign?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87355/why-cat-grep-and-other-commands-cant-understand-files-starting-with-minus-sign?)

Comment: I believe that the comments above are suggesting that this should be posted in https://unix.stackexchange.com instead of on this site (if you were wondering where else you could go for help)

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I moved the question to unix.stackexchange.com as suggested by @Jeff

Answer (score 5):

When you need to specify a file name that starts with a dash as argument to a command, which might interpret it as option instead, you can write the absolute or explicit relative path to the file instead:

```
mv /path/to/-a a
mv ./-a a
```

Alternatively *some* (not all) commands support `--` as separator between options and positional arguments. This depends on the specific command you use though.

```
mv -- -a a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mv -- -a a
```

The '--' tells the shell that what follows after this is not an option to the command.

All your variants give, after the evaluation of quotes and backslash, the command `mv -a a` so you are told that the option '-a' is not a valid option to the mv command and that you should give a target operand.